# How to prevent refreshes from blowing out sobjects and tables

Tags: sobject, table, sandbox-refresh

I have created an sobject the essentially manages a callback URL to app servers we have running in-house:

- http://devmyapp01.example.com
- http://qamyapp01.example.com
- http://myapp01.example.com

Above, I would have 3 sobjects, 1 representing my "dev" URL, 1 for my "qa" URL and 1 for live.

Anytime we do a refresh of our production SalesForce, the instances of these sobjects will be overwritten with production URLs (prod will overwrite qa and dev). Once this happens, any internal testing we do against these sobjects will wreak havoc on our production SalesForce system.

What can be done to prevent this or mitigate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you add a field to the SObject called something like "ApplicableOrganizationId" and then route all access through a method that looks something like this:

```
public String getCallbackUrl() {
    MyObject__c[] sobs = [
            select CallbackUrl__c
            from MyObject__c
            where ApplicableOrganizationId__c = :UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
            ];
    return sobs.size() == 1 ? sobs[0].CallbackUrl__c : null;
}
```

Then in production ensure that the production, QA sandbox and UAT sandbox organization IDs are set appropriately. (These can be found from Setup -> Company Profile -> Company Information ->  Salesforce.com Organization ID.)

Checking the `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` will only tell you whether you are in a production org or a sandbox, not which sandbox you are in.

Comment: Thanks @Keith C (+1) - but I think this will only help me tell which environment each sobject "lives in"; I don't think this will help me after a refresh, as all non-production sobjects will now have production URLs. Can you elaborate a bit more and help me understand? Thanks again!

Comment: @Venkat You said you had an SObject already that I assume had one row containing the URL. I'm suggesting having 3 rows (could be a list custom setting) and populating them in the production org. So when the 3 rows are replicated to the sandbox, the above code will ensure the right one is used in the right org.

Comment: I'm sorry again @Keitch C (+1) - not trying to be difficult here but as soon as I started coding up your solution I ran into a mental blocker here: when you say "3 rows" do you mean 3 instances of the SObject, where each SOBject has a different ApplicableOrganizationId? And are you suggesting that I add these to production so that they are *always* copied over to non-production after a refresh?

Comment: @Venkat Yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of options in this solution in stack overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507718/how-do-i-detect-the-environment-in-salesforce

I prefer the answer by Ron
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12985768/3968579